# How to use tail with syslog file wrap-around?

Tags: linux, syslog

Upon certain conditions `/var/log/syslog` file is saved to  `/var/log/syslog.0` and a new empty `/var/log/syslog`
is created to serve the system.

The problem is - if `tail -f /var/log/syslog` runs during
the above switch, then `tail` stops showing anything because
of the `syslog` file switch.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the -F option to get the behavior you desire.  For example: `tail -F /var/log/syslog`